# What IC is this TO-220?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, to220

This IC, 5TB06-700BW, is sitting on a motor controller PCB (manufactured in 1998). Pin 1 and 2 are attached to 230V lines, while pin 3 is attached to the output-pin on a [U2010B phase control IC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1804162236_Wuxi-Siyon-Microelectronics-Tech-U2010B_C143004.pdf). The motor does not run so I suspect that the TO-220 IC is dead, but I cannot find any information on google regarding what kind of IC it is so I cannot confirm it.

What IC is it?

[image]

Comment: triacs will usually fail short circuit. Open circuit if they exploded - but that is visually obvious.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the first '5' is a 'B".

A BTB06 is a '[6A standard and Snubberless™ Triac](https://www.st.com/en/thyristors-scr-and-ac-switches/btb06.html)'